# How do you use the variable i in a for loop, to call upon other variables in R?

Tags: r, for-loop

Im new to R and have trouble correctly formulating my problem, but I think you understand it when you see the code.

```
var_1 <- 10

var_2 <- 20

var_3 <- 30

var_4 <- 40

for (i in 1:4){
  
var_i <- var_i * i 

}
```

This (logically) does not work, but how do I make it work?

Comment: You may use `paste` and `get/assign` `for(i in 1:4){assign(paste0("var_", i), get(paste0("var_", i)) * i)}`  Now check the object values `> var_1
[1] 10
> var_2
[1] 40
> var_3
[1] 90`

Comment: Okay this works! 

Now how do work only with var_i.
For example I have a matrix made as mat_1, mat_2, mat_3 and mat_4. How do I change the colnames values of all those things to the same thing for example c(1:11).

Same goes for example dataframes: df_1, df_2, df_3 and df_4. How do I call that dataframe?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: While you can manage your objects by giving them distinctive names, in the medium run you'll save yourself headache by collecting them in lists or grouping them into larger matrices/dataframes which you split (if at all) as required - rather than having objects all over your workplace. Example: `my_matrices <- list(mat_1 = matrix(1:9, 3, 3), mat_2  = matrix(rnorm(16),,4)` ... `print(my_matrices$mat1)`

Comment: In R I would strongly discourage you from writing code like this. Using `assign/get` often just cause more trouble. It's better to use proper collections of values in R like vectors and lists that allow for easy indexing by name or number. Then you can use all the built in vectorized functions to easily transform all the values at once. With this example it would be `vals <- c(10,20,30,40); vals <- vals * seq_along(vals)`